# Facebook oauth page not displayed properly

Tags: android, facebook, oauth

I'm loading a web page in WebView. That page a contains link for facebook authentication. When pressing that link, facebook oauth page is loaded. Here, the problem is, the UI fields are not rendered properly. Please see the screenshot [image]

Note: But, the same is loading fine on mobile browser.

Comment: can see source code?

Comment: Removing the custom user agent setting for the web view fixes the issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please ensure that your facebook login url contains display=touch property.
if not add that property and check it again.

if that doesn't fix your issue,
remove/add user agent string of your webview to any known mobile browsers user agent string.

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(<user agent string>);
```

Comment: Works by removing custom user agent. Thanks!